# Unable to submit a struts html form via IE 8 in Struts 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, struts-1

I'm having trouble with submitting my HTML form via IE 8. It is kinda weird because it works perfectly fine in firefox. When I click the submit button nothing happens.

**HTML Code:**

```
<html:form action="/jsp/fileUploadAction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileUploadForm" type="com.fileuploadtest.form.FileUploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="files[0]" style="display: none;" onchange="javascript:selectFiles(0);" id="file0"/>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" id="uploadButton" />
</html:form>

<h5 style="text-align:center"><i style="color:#ccc"><small>Max File Size: 2 Mb - Display last 20 files</small></i></h5>

<table id="uploaded-files" class="table" border="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Cancel Action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload All" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
     alert('Button clicked');
     $( '[name="fileUploadForm"]' ).submit();
 });
```

Comment: Try putting your submit button inside your form, ie in <html:form> </html:form> tags and see if it works.

Comment: Why bother using a submit button if you're doing it via JS anyway?

Comment: Dave: Ya it could have been a normal HTML button, but I simply did the test code and the submit button was outside the form that's why I was invoking the submit from JS.

Susie: Tried that as well before posting the question here, but its not working. I changed my IE from 8 to 11 and everything works fine. Kinda awkward. Thanks for the help :)